# How can it be explained that the natural fifth of an euphonium is not in the “natural fifth pitch?

Tags: tuning, instruments, overtones

I practice with 3 different Euphoniums, a brass-instrument like a small tuba. One of them - a Yamaha training instrument with 4 valves in a row - has a bad intonation at the natural fifth (upper G) actually the f ...
which can hardly be compensated by lip tension or embouchure. I have no idea what could be the reason of this phenomenon as this tone  is part of the overtone series.

Comment: The euphonium has its own particular set of problems. I suggest you search online for *euphonum pitch problems*. You will discover many useful articles, e.g. http://www.dwerden.com/CompensatingSystem.pdf ... https://merbrassresourcefile.weebly.com/uploads/4/0/5/8/40583795/instr_may_1981_eu029.pdf

Answer (score 2):

A perfect air column contained in a perfect, straight tube, plays the notes of the harmonic series.

A real-world instrument, with all its twists, bends and constrictions, doesn't.

Part of the art of designing a good instrument is minimising these imperfections.  Or the designer may have taken the attitude 'Ok the open note is out of tune, but it's fine with an alternate fingering'. Try 1+3 or 4.

(I think that's right.  We're talking in 'Bb transposed' notation?   Anyway, try SOME alternative fingering.)

You think THAT's bad?  Look at the overtone series of a church bell.  It bears very little resemblence to the theoretical harmonic series.  It isn't a simple tuning fork, designed for purity of pitch, it's a very complex resonant system. The 'hum note' may be a major 7th below the 'strike note'!  This isn't the place to discuss it fully, just know that real instruments don't have a nice tidy overtone structure!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_tone

Comment: Yes, I‘m talking about Bb instrument. My question is concerning the fifth and I can‘t understand that it sound so much wrong as it doesn‘t need any walve and no compenation. And with all other instruments I never had this problem. I could even post a piece of the Tokyo Staff Band where you can hear the same negative effect.

Comment: Read my answer again.  A euphonium is not a laboratory demonstration of acoustical principles, it's an imperfect, real-world object.

Comment: I can understand a reputable band using instruments with an out-of-tune open G.   I can't understand them failing to solve this with an alternative fingering!   Let's hear the piece?